# Unexpected characters in saved file using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog

Code:

```
private void btnSaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
    {
        string path = sfd.FileName;
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(path));
        foreach (string s in hello)
        {
            bw.Write(s + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

output for

[image: this]

I really don't know how to get rid of those characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write to a text file do not use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx). It appends the length of the string which explains why you are observing those strange characters.

You could use [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx):

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(path)
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    foreach (string s in hello) 
    {
        writer.Write(s + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

or in this particular example you could shorten all this code to a single line of code using the [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) method:

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = sfd.FileName;
    File.WriteAllLines(path, hello);
}
```

Also be careful! You have a trailing `;` after your `if` statement. This means that the write to the file will **always** happen, no matter whether the user confirmed or canceled the file dialog. Notice how I removed it in my last example.

Comment: To add, a `BinaryWriter` appends the length (7-bit encoded binary form) of the string before writing the string. That's what causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
```

StreamWriter is very ideal for writing text in files. While BinaryWriter writes primitive types in binary to a stream and supports writing strings in a specific encoding.

Comment: Thank you and i used

 <code>
foreach (string s in hello)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(s);                 
                    }
</code>